# sudo instead of root sometimes asks for password

Tags: sudo

Ubuntu 13.7

I'm not set up as root and don't want to be. But sometimes /not always/ but sometimes when I try to run a sudo command, I'm asked for my password.  I type in my user password, since I don't think I have a root pw, not being root, right?) and the password isn't accepted. Why does this happen? For instance, I tried a sudo command and got this terminal response:
"user password accepted on login but rejected on terminal"

Comment: Are you setup as an administrator? Sudo is a substitute for root. Just make sure that in the settings, and the user accounts menu, you're all set up as a admin.

Comment: Please post the exact command you ran as well as the exact error message. When using sudo, use your login password. In addition, please post the version of ubuntu you are using and the output of the command `id`

Answer (score 2):

You are always asked for your sudo password unless you already provided it in the last 15 minutes. This password is not to log in as root but your personal password. root user is disabled by default in all Ubuntu installations.